# How to make color background full

Tags: html, css, background

How do I make the background color touch each end. I am fairly new to html and CSS below I have the code that I input for the background. Please let me know exactly what I need to change in my code. I know some of it needs to be changed I just don't know exactly what I need to change.

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <hr>
  <h2 class="white">Documentation Examples</h2>

  <a>
    <ul class="documentations">
      <li>
        Savings or Checkings Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Stocks, Dividends, Bonds or Debentures
      </li>
      <li>
        Life Insurance Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Escrow Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Negotiable Instruments, Certified Checks, Money Orders, or Travelers Checks.
      </li>
      <li>
        Safe Deposit Box Contents
      </li>
      <li>
        Business Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Corporation/Business Entity/Partnership
      </li>
      <li>
        Governmental Agency Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Miscellaneous Accounts
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZY7S)

Answer (score 1):

Nest your code in a `body` and use `margin: 0;` in your stylesheet. See below.

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="black">
  <hr>
  <h2 class="white">Documentation Examples</h2>

  <a>
    <ul class="documentations">
      <li>
        Savings or Checkings Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Stocks, Dividends, Bonds or Debentures
      </li>
      <li>
        Life Insurance Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Escrow Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Negotiable Instruments, Certified Checks, Money Orders, or Travelers Checks.
      </li>
      <li>
        Safe Deposit Box Contents
      </li>
      <li>
        Business Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Corporation/Business Entity/Partnership
      </li>
      <li>
        Governmental Agency Accounts
      </li>
      <li>
        Miscellaneous Accounts
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is still not covering the upper part. Pls consider fixing it.

Comment: @TrueAlpha touch each end meaning side to side

Comment: Can you explain a little better. I didn't understand.

Comment: @TrueAlpha SO snippets render a body by default if it's included or not. So you need to declare `body { margin: 0; }` to reach from left to right. If OP want's top-spacing removed they can use `.black { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100vw;}`

Answer (score 0):

`div` tag always have margin and you have to remove it with `margin : 0`. and if you want to display black `background-color` on your entire screen you have to give `height: 100vh`

```
.black {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white; 
  height: 100vh;
}

.body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct, but you need to wrap the css in `<style type="text/css">...</style>` tags.

This should be in the `<head>...</head>` tag on your page:

```
<head>
    <!-- title and other things go here -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .black {
            background-color: black;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove all the paddings and margins by adding `margin:0` and `padding:0`. Like this:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This would remove all the paddings and margin so the background will be fully covered.

Comment: This doesn't work...